# Angular Material Table cannot show data

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material-table

I'm following online tutorial to create a mat table to display some hard coded data. But the table is empty. I'm new to angular and html/css. Does anyone know what causes the mat table cannot display data?
[image]
[image]

Here's my typescript file "new-page.component.ts":

```
import {
  Component, OnInit, ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTable, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatPaginator} from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {MatDialog} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {NewPageDialogComponent} from "./new-page-dialog/new-page-dialog.component";
import {SampleData} from "../../models/sample-data"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-page',
  templateUrl: './new-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-page.component.css']
})

export class NewPageComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'];

  data: SampleData[] = [{
    var1 : "value1",
    var2 : "value2",
    var3 : "value3"
  }, {
    var1 : "value4",
    var2 : "value5",
    var3 : "value6",
  }]

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<SampleData> = new MatTableDataSource<SampleData>(this.data);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SampleData>(this.data)
  }

  @ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable<SampleData>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

}
```

Here's my html file new-page.component.html:

```
<div>
  <h2>vin group criteria / rpo restriction criteria</h2>
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="data">
      <!-- var1 Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="var1">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> var1 </mat-header-cell>
        <td *matCellDef="let SampleData" mat-cell> {{SampleData.var1}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="var2">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> var2 </mat-header-cell>
        <td *matCellDef="let SampleData" mat-cell> {{SampleData.var2}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="var3">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> var3 </mat-header-cell>
        <td *matCellDef="let SampleData" mat-cell> {{SampleData.var3}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" mat-header-row></tr>
      <tr *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" mat-row></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 30, 60, 100]" aria-label="Select page of users"></mat-paginator>

</div>
```

Here's my css file:

```
table {
  width: 80%;
}

.mat-cell {
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}

.mat-form-field {
  width: 100%;
}

.mat-column-actions {
  width: 10%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

td.mat-cell, th.mat-sort-header {
  padding: 16px 16px;
}

mat-header-cell, mat-cell {
  justify-content: center;
}

.example-list {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  min-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.example-box {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: move;
  background: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.cdk-drag-preview {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
  0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
  0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.example-box:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.example-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .example-box:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

Comment: any errors in the console? It may be useful to prepare a reproduction of this issue on stackblitz :)

Comment: @MaciejWojcik I've posted the screenshot of console in question. Looks it has ERROR Error: MatSortHeader must be placed within a parent element with the MatSort directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have any other errors, correct your template data binding and add `matSort` directive to your `mat-table` table html tag. You are binding `[dataSource]` in your html to `data` property not `dataSource` property.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
```

not

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data">
```

Comment: I changed data to dataSource. The table is still empty. Not sure what I missed

Comment: Just open browser inspector and go console tab and show the message there.

Comment: Thanks! I've post the screenshot in question. It has "ERROR Error: MatSortHeader must be placed within a parent element with the MatSort directive.
"Sorry, I didn't know I can use inspector. Zero front end experience.

Comment: Very simple! Errors are the key to get into solutions. I updated my response. You have to add a missing directive in your HTML. matSort is missing.

Comment: Thanks! It displays data now. Lol I feel angular development is more complex than creating rest API

Answer (score 1):

Add `@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;` to components class and add following function

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

Because MatSort is missing in the component class.